# Create SEQUENCE and TRIGGER by external procedure

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a table that is only created by passing in this procedure.
This is kinda the **CREATE** trigger and **SEQUENCE** generator.
*(We can't stop the database to create **TRIGGER** and **SEQ.**, I've already tried to ask for this several times... So got to create it by hand)*

```
DO TRANSACTION ON ERROR UNDO, RETRY:

    FIND LAST mensagem NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.

    IF AVAIL im THEN
        INextID = mensagem.mensagem_id + 1.
    ELSE
        INextID = 01.

    IF CAN-FIND(mensagem WHERE mensagem.mensagem_id = iNextID) THEN
        UNDO, RETRY.
    
    CREATE mensagem.

    /* mensagem_id is a unique, primary index */
    ASSIGN 
        mensagem.mensagem_id = INextID
        mensagem.field1 = value1
        mensagem.field2 = value2
        .
    
END.
```

This procedure is accessed several times during a minute, and sometimes may occur on two programs calling it at the same time, occuring in trying to create two objects with the same value.
My issue is the following: How can I prevent the error `mensagem already exists with mensagem_id 'INextID'`? 
*(Considers INextID as the next number)*.

When this error occurs, it's not looping thru the **TRANSACTION BLOCK** and is not creating the information on the table.
*(I've already tried to call the .P with NO-ERROR param, but no success neither)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example code you are (probably) getting an occasional collision in the ASSIGN statement because a small amount of time can pass between the FIND, the CAN-FIND, and the CREATE & ASSIGN. And during that interval another process can slip in and use the value that you were hoping to use. So you need to add NO-ERROR to the ASSIGN and then handle the suppressed error by first detecting it and then retrying.

Something like this:

```
ASSIGN 
        mensagem.mensagem_id = INextID
        mensagem.field1 = value1
        mensagem.field2 = value2
  NO-ERROR.

if error-status:num-messages > 0 then
  undo, retry.
```

However - using a sequence is the best way to prevent collisions on sequence numbers and that would be a much better approach.

You can add sequences online, there is no need to stop the database to do that. You can add triggers online too if you are on OE12.2 or better.

Comment: I'll take a look at this... I was considering that the sequence was attached to a table, so wasn't possible to add online. But after some searching, I saw that is related to the table.

But on the topic, this seems to fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: *is related to the database...

Created some tests and dump/load of a sequence went successfully.